Finding $a$ that minimizes the maximum value of $f(x)=\cos(2x)+\cos(x+a)$

For any real number $a$, let $f(x)=\cos(2x)+\cos(x+a)$ be a function with respect to $x$. Find $$\min\limits_{a\in\mathbb{R}}\max\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)$$ Or, in plain words, find the value of $a$ that minimizes the maximum value of $f(x)$.

This problem originated from a high school physics exam question on mass-spring oscillations, which has stumped me yesterday after numerous attempts. It would be helpful if anyone could solve it with the most elementary tools possible. Thank you for your help.
Edit: the reason why I could not solve it was due to the $+a$ factor. If not for that, $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$ and this would be simply solved via completing the square. Here, the maximum need to be minimized via all possible values of $a$.
Edit 2: From plotting $f(x)$ over multiple instance of $a$, $a=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ should yields the smallest maximum of $\dfrac{9}{8}$.

Solving $f'(x)=-2\sin(2x)-\sin(x+a)=0$ in terms of $a$ is quite messy...

$x\in \mathbb{R}?$

Yes, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

@Boopy: Looking at WolframAlpha's solution, "messy" is an understatement.

I agree that this is definitely an involved problem. One possible approach.
Differentiating with respect to x defines our critical $x_c$'s to be given by the equation
$$ 0 = 2 \sin 2x_c + \sin(x_c+a). \tag{1} \label{1}$$
Inserting this into our equation:
$$ g(a) = f(x_c(a);a) = \cos(2x_c) + \cos(x_c + a) $$
Differentiating with respect to $a$ now:
$$ g'(a) = - 2 \sin(x_c) x_c' - \sin(x_c+a)(x_c' + 1) = 0.$$
Using the condition from \eqref{1} leads to
$$ \sin(x_c + a) = 0 \implies x_c + a = n\pi $$
Using \eqref{1} again shows that $2x_c = m \pi$ and so $a = \frac{\pi}{2}(2k+1)$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$.
From this, we can see that
\begin{align}
f(x;k\pi/2) & = \cos(2x) + \cos(x + k\pi/2) \\
& = \cos(2x) - (-1)^k \sin x \\
& = 1 - 2 \sin^2 x - (-1)^k \sin x \\
& = -2 \left(\sin^2x + \frac{1}{2}(-1)^k \sin x \right) + 1 \\
& = -2\left(\sin x + \frac{1}{4}(-1)^k \right)^2 + \frac{1}{8} + 1 \\
& = -2\left(\sin x + \frac{1}{4}(-1)^k \right)^2 + \frac{9}{8}.
\end{align}

I have a question. You claim $x_c + a = n\pi$. This seems not true.
(i) First, when $a = \pi/2$ and $x_c + a = n\pi$, we have
$\cos 2x_c + \cos(x_c + a) = \cos 2(n\pi - a)

\cos (n\pi) = -1 + (-1)^n \le 0 < \frac98$. (See next comment).


(Cont'd) (ii) Second, when $a = \pi/2$, consider $\max_x [\cos 2x + \cos (x + \pi/2)]$. The optimal $x$ is $x = 2\pi - \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$ or $x = \pi + \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$. Clearly, $x + \pi/2 = n\pi$ is not a solution for $\max_x [\cos 2x + \cos (x + \pi/2)]$.
Actually, in $[0, 2\pi]$, there are four critical/stationary points: $x_1 = \pi/2$, $x_2 = 3\pi/2$, $x_3 = 2\pi - \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$, and $x_4 = \pi + \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$. We have $x_1 + a = \pi$ and $x_2 + a = 2\pi$. However, they are not the optimal points.

One probable issue is that $g(a)=f(x_c(a), a)=\cos(2x_c)+\cos(x_c+a)$ is not a single function as there are many $x_c$ that satisfy condition (1). I just view the solutions of $a$ as the candidates and separately investigate $f(x)$ under those $a$'s.

@Boopy I used quartic formula to obtain the closed form of $x_c$ (for $a\in [0, \pi/2]$, complicated expression). It seems that $f(x_c, a)$ is strictly decreasing on $[0, \pi/2]$, and it does not hold $\frac{\mathrm{d} f(x_c,a)}{\mathrm{d} a}\vert_{a=\pi/2} = 0$. (Also, it seems $x_c(a)$ is not differentiable at $a = \pi/2$.)

@Boopy Let $a \in (0, \pi)$. Let $x_c(a) := \arg\max_{x\in [0, 2\pi]}\ [\cos 2x + \cos(x + a)]$. If $a\ne \pi/2$, $x_c(a)$ is unique. If $a = \pi/2$, there are exactly two values of $x_c$, that is,
$x_c = \pi + \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}, \quad 2\pi - \arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$. $\lim_{a\to (\pi/2)^{+}} x_c(a) = \pi + \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$, and $\lim_{a\to (\pi/2)^{-}} x_c(a) = 2\pi - \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$. $x_c(a)$ is discontinuous at $a = \pi/2$. $\sin x_c(a)$ is continuous, but is not differentiable at $a = \pi/2$. I think this is why the approach fails.

Soluton. We have
$$f(x, a) := \cos 2x + \cos(x + a) 
= 2\cos^2 x - 1 + \cos x \cos a - \sin x \sin a.$$
First, if $\cos a = 0$, we have
$$\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} f(x, a) = \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \, (2\cos^2 x - 1 \pm \sin x) = \frac98. $$
(Note: $\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \, (2\cos^2 x - 1 + \sin x) = \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \, (2\cos^2 x - 1 - \sin x) = \frac98$.)
Second, if $\cos a \ne 0$, we choose $x_1$ such that
$$\cos x_1 = \mathrm{sign}(\cos a)\cdot \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}, \quad
\sin x_1 = -\mathrm{sign}(\sin a)\cdot \frac14$$
where $\mathrm{sign}(\cdot)$ is defined as: $\mathrm{sign}(u) = 1$ if $u \ge 0$ and $\mathrm{sign}(u) = -1$ if $u < 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
 f(x_1, a) &= \frac78 + \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}|\cos a|
 + \frac14 |\sin a|\\
 &> \frac78 + \frac{1}{4}|\cos a|
 + \frac14 |\sin a|\\
 &\ge \frac78 + \frac{1}{4}\cos^2 a
 + \frac14\sin^2 a\\
 &= \frac98.
\end{align*}
Thus, we have $\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} f(x, a) \ge f(x_1, a) > \frac98$.
As a result, we have
$$\min_{a\in \mathbb{R}} \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} f(x, a) = \frac98.$$
We are done.

Remark. About the numbers $\cos x = \pm\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$ and $\sin x = \pm \frac{1}{4}$:
Since the OP guess $\frac98$, we consider the system of equations
$f(x, a) = \frac98$ and $\frac{\partial f(x, a)}{\partial x} = 0$, that is
$-4\cos x \sin x = \sin x \cos a + \cos x \sin a$
and $\frac{17}{8} - 2\cos^2 x = \cos x \cos a - \sin x \sin a$.
Since $(\sin x \cos a + \cos x \sin a)^2 + (\cos x \cos a - \sin x \sin a)^2 = 1$, we have
$(-4\cos x \sin x)^2 + (\frac{17}{8} - 2\cos^2 x)=1$ which results in $16\cos^2 x = 15$. So we have $\cos x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$ and $\sin x = \pm \frac14$.

How did $\mathrm{arctan}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$ came into this solution?

@Boopy Equivalently, we solve the system of equations $\frac{\partial f(x, a)}{\partial x} = 0$ and $f(x, a) = \frac98$, after eliminating $\cos a, \sin a$ using the relation $\sin^2 a + \cos^2 a = 1$, we get $\cos x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$.

@Boopy I have improved my answer to be shorter.

Thank you for your solution. I actually appreciate one that would not require my “Edit 2” guess more, as this is an exam question. No graphical calculators are allowed, so the guess cannot be made before solving this question.

@Boopy I understand. Actually, we can do it without knowing "Edit 2" etc. by calculus, although it is more complicated than current answer.

If your calculus solution differs from @Gregory’s, feel free to post another answer. I will be reading them all.

@Boopy By the way, nonuser's answer leads to a reasonable guess $9/8$ and $\cos a = 0$. Then, proceed along my answer.

@Boopy I think Gregory's solution is incorrect. Gregory claims that $x_c + a = n\pi$ for the optimal $a$ and $x_c = x_c(a) = \mathrm{argmax} f(x, a)$. For example, $a = \pi/2, x_c = 2\pi - \arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$ is a solution to the problem, but $a + x_c \ne n\pi$. Please take a look at it.

My second solution.
Let $f_0(a) := \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + a)]$.
We have
$f_0(a) = f_0(a + \pi) = f_0(\pi - a)$.
Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
 \min_{a\in \mathbb{R}} \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + a)] &= \min_{a\in [0, \pi/2]} \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + a)]\\
 &= \min_{a\in [0, \pi/2]} \max_{x\in [0, 2\pi]} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + a)].
\end{align*}
We can prove that
$$\min_{a\in [0, \pi/2]} \max_{x\in [0, 2\pi]} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + a)] = \min_{a\in [0, \pi/2]} \max_{x\in [7\pi/4,\, 2\pi]} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + a)]. \tag{1}$$
(The proof is given at the end.)
Note that, for all $x\in [7\pi/4, 2\pi]$ and $a\in [0, \pi/2]$,
$$\cos(x + a) - \cos(x + \pi/2)
= 2\sin (\pi/4 - a/2) \sin (x + a/2 + \pi/4) \ge 0.$$
We have
\begin{align*}
 &\min_{a\in [0, \pi/2]} \max_{x\in [7\pi/4,\, 2\pi]} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + a)]\\
 \ge{}& \min_{a\in [0, \pi/2]} \max_{x\in [7\pi/4,\, 2\pi]} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + \pi/2)]\\
 ={}& \frac98.
\end{align*}
Also, when $a = \pi/2$, we have
$$\max_{x\in [7\pi/4,\, 2\pi]} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + a)]
= \max_{x\in [7\pi/4,\, 2\pi]} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + \pi/2)] = \frac98.$$
Thus, we have
$$\min_{a\in [0, \pi/2]} \max_{x\in [7\pi/4,\, 2\pi]} \ [\cos 2x + \cos (x + a)] = \frac98.$$
We are done.

Proof of (1).
For $a \in [0, \pi/2]$, it suffices to prove that, for all $x\in [0, 7\pi/4]$,
$$f(x, a) := \cos 2x + \cos (x + a) \le f(2\pi, a) = 1 + \cos a.$$
(i) We have, for all $x\in [0, \pi/2]$,
$$f(x, a) \le f(0, a) = 1 + \cos a$$
since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
= -4\sin x \cos x - \sin x \cos a - \cos x \sin a \le 0$.
(ii) We have, for all $x\in (\pi/2, \pi]$,
$$f(x, a) \le \cos 2x \le 1,$$
since $\pi/2 \le x + a \le 3\pi/2$.
(iii) If $x \in [\pi, 5\pi/4]$, then $3\pi - x \in [7\pi/4, 2\pi]$ and we have
$$f(3\pi - x, a) - f(x, a)
= - 2\cos x \cos a \ge 0.$$
(iv) We have, for all $x\in [5\pi/4, 7\pi/4]$,
$$f(x, a) \le \cos (x + a) \le 1,$$
since $\cos 2x \le 0$.
From (i)-(iv), the desired result follows.

I will change your notation just a bit and write $f_a(x)$ for the function. Let $a_0$ be the value of $a$ that minimizes the maximum value of $f_a(x)$. We want to find an explicit value for $a_0$.
For every $a$, we have that $\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}}f_{a_0}(x) \leq \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f_{a}(x)$. Therefore,
$$\int_0^{\pi}f_{a_0}(x)dx \leq \int_0^{\pi}f_{a}(x)dx.$$
Solving gives
$$-2\sin(a_0) \leq -2\sin(a),$$
or in other words
$$\sin(a) \leq \sin(a_0).$$
Since this must be true for every value of $a$, we find that $\sin(a_0)=1$. Thus we may take $a_0 = \pi/2$.

The way I see it, $f(x)$ can be split into two separate functions:
$g(x)=\cos(2x)\\
h(x)=\cos(x+a)$
We know that $g(x)$ has peaks at $x=\pi n$, and $h(x)$ has peaks at $x=2\pi n-a$ (where $n$ is an integer). If we temporarily set $a=0$, then we can visualize how every peak of $h(x)$ will coincide with a peak of $g(x)$, which isn't optimal for minimizing $f(x)$. That means the value of $a$ cannot be $\pi n$ (a multiple of $\pi$) because that would just translate the peaks of $h(x)$ onto the peaks of $g(x)$ again. Therefore, $a$ must be in between $\pi n$, that is, $\pi n+\frac{\pi}{2}$. This would ensure that the peaks of $h(x)$ would never coincide with those of $g(x)$ - in fact, they would coincide with the troughs of $g(x)$. And we know $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is precisely correct because any slight translation to the right or left would again amplify the corresponding peak of $g(x)$.
